# Hollow or tiny valley?

Tags: expressions

In English we have the word *hollow* which is a very small low place or valley, more like a portion of a stream gorge, for example. Someone told me *la combe* might be a good word. Any other opinions?

Comment: WordReference suggests *enfoncement* (from *enfoncer*, to dig or sink) or *dénivellation* (from *niveau*, level — an unlevel-ness).

Answer (score 2):

A *combe* is usually at the top of a mountain. I feel *un vallon* is probably closer to *a hollow*, which can be found in a plain or within a valley. There's also *une dépression* and (more colloquially) *un creux* (litteral equivalent of a hollow) but I feel they refer more to the shape of land than to the location. So you could say

> Il y a une dépression derrière le village
>
> Il y a un vallon derrière le village
>
> Je vais au vallon derrière le village

but not

> (*) Je vais à la dépression derrière le village

Comment: "the theater in the hollow" is what I'm trying to get. Google translate says: "le théâtre dans le creux" but perhaps "le théâtre de le creux" is more idiomatically correct?

Comment: No, vallon would be better

Comment: @147pm the problem with *creux* is that it describes the shape of the land more than the location, and wouldn't be used like "hollow" that way. For example "sleepy hollow" is translated as "vallon endormi"